# show category featured image in category page

Tags: php, wordpress, image, categories, wordpress-featured-image

I have featured images for categories and I'd like to show them on the category page, like here: http://aquadiva.it/en/category/beauty-en/

here's what my category.php looks like

```
<?php

/**
 * The template for displaying Category Archive pages.
 *
 * @package Cryout Creations
 * @subpackage Nirvana
 * @since Nirvana 1.0
 */

get_header(); ?>

    <section id="container" class="<?php echo nirvana_get_layout_class(); ?>">
        <div id="content" role="main">
        <?php cryout_before_content_hook(); ?>

        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

            <header class="page-header">
                <h1 class="page-title"><div class="page-title-text"><?php
                    printf( __( '%s', 'nirvana' ), '<span>' . single_cat_title( '', false ) . '</span>' );
                ?></div></h1>

                <?php
                    $category_description = category_description();
                    if ( ! empty( $category_description ) )
                        echo apply_filters( 'category_archive_meta', '<div class="category-archive-meta">' . $category_description . '</div>' );
                ?>
            </header>

            <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>

            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
            $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID));
            ?>

                <?php
                    /* Include the Post-Format-specific template for the content.
                     * If you want to overload this in a child theme then include a file
                     * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Format name) and that will be used instead.
                     */
                    get_template_part( 'content/content', get_post_format() );
                ?>

            <?php endwhile; ?>

                <?php if($nirvana_pagination=="Enable") nirvana_pagination(); else nirvana_content_nav( 'nav-below' ); ?>

        <?php else : ?>

            <article id="post-0" class="post no-results not-found">
                <header class="entry-header">
                    <h1 class="entry-title"><?php _e( 'Nothing Found', 'nirvana' ); ?></h1>
                </header><!-- .entry-header -->

                <div class="entry-content">
                    <p><?php _e( 'Apologies, but no results were found for the requested archive. Perhaps searching will help find a related post.', 'nirvana' ); ?></p>
                    <?php get_search_form(); ?>
                </div><!-- .entry-content -->
            </article><!-- #post-0 -->

        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php cryout_after_content_hook(); ?>
        </div><!-- #content -->
    <?php nirvana_get_sidebar(); ?>
    </section><!-- #primary -->
```

what am I missing?

Comment: Please add some information about your error.

Comment: no real error. the image just won't show. so I looked around your page, and I actually adde this: " ...$src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID));
            ?>" to get the image to show, but it does not do the trick. there should be an image showing before the ist of the posts for the category. I'd like it to be before the title, but I am not that picky - just as long as I can make it show

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to do what I wanted with a new plugin (I deleted the "get the image" plugin and used "categories images"). everythin's working fine